# With operator overloading, how does the C# compiler decide which implementation applies with mixed-type operands?

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

```
int normal;
int? nullable;
var x = normal/nullable; // expression evaluates to Nullable<int>
var y = nullable/normal; // also Nullable<int>
```

EDIT: My original question was a bit inviting to answers of a kind I'm not looking for. The title actually sums up the question, and the example used to illustrate it was poorly chosen.

In the above, there is only one possibility for the compiler: int.divide operator doesn't support nullable int operands, int? does, and that settles it. There is no ambiguity and no need for presedence rules of any kind.

But what if I have two types that overload the same operator, say divide for the sake of example, and they both support the other type as one of the operands?

There are really two questions here:

1) How does the compiler decide whether to use the operator from Type1 or Type2 when both types support Type1/Type2 and Type2/Type1? Is there a left-to-right precedence (for binary ops) or something else?

2) Are there any assumptions about operations such as symmetry? In other words, must A + B always equal B + A, or is that up to the type?

In the end these questions are perhaps slightly academical, as in many practical scenarios any flavour of method (whether virtual methods, ordinary instance methods, or static "utilty" methods, even if the latter most closely resembles the operator) can be used to the same end. Then again there may be instances where there is real value to be gained from enabling the much-easier-to-read syntax that results from using operators instead of normal method syntax. (Syntax being the only reason why languages have operators in the first place; it is after all just a method.)

Answer (score 2):

> how does the compiler decide that it's the nullable type's division operator and not the regular int's operator that applies?

Because the 'regular' operator could not be applied.
This of course uses the normal operators:

```
 var x = normal/nullable.Value;
```

But when you combine normal and nullable, consider that nullable is 'unknnown'. How much is `x + unknown` ? It is unknown again. And because the result could be `null` the result-type of the expression has to be nullable.

Comment: Yes, the behaivor totally makes sense. And it's true that in my perhaps poorly chosen example the int divide operator could not apply. But what if both operands define the operator and support the argument types? And is division always symmetrical, or is it possible to make a type with asymmetrical division? (e.g. matrices, IIRC.) I don't have any particular use case in mind, it just occured to me that I'm not really sure. I've never actually used operator overloading since leaving uni.. :)

Comment: Sorry, please ignore that. Division is of course asymmetrical (if that's even the right term) in every ordinary sense; 5/2 != 2/5, and quite clearly operand order matters. Presumably the same is true for those ops that are normally symmetrical, e.g. +, so a type *can* make it so that A + B != B + A (in general). But I leave that open for confirmation.

Comment: Symmetry is not involved, `A op Unknown` is always unknown regardless of 'op'.  With the possible exceptions of `||` and `&&`.

Comment: Holtermann: yes, my example was bad and that makes sense for Nullable<T>. I've rephrased my question in an attempt to improve it, but there haven't been any takers. I guess I should settle it experimentally, but I haven't much time to experiment right now.